# Visual Studio, C# how to add a doc file as a resource

Tags: c#, ms-office

I am trying to add a word document (.doc) to my project as a resource so I could open it with a button.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: It is very easy. Even without VS knowledge, (almost) everyone can add a file resource to the project.

Comment: I had a question like your's but I've found another answer of that(Use Settings instead of Resources). See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379526/c-sharp-how-to-add-string-to-resources).

Answer (score 5):

You can take the following steps to add a doc file into as resource into your project:

1. Right-click your project and select the "Properties" option.
2. Then click the "Resources" tab and it will show the dialog for you to add resources in the design time.
3. The default page is for add String resources, you can select the combobox in the top-right to select the "file" item.
4. Then click the "Add Resource" button to select the doc file and click OK.
5. At last, the doc file will show in the blank area. It means that you have added it successfully.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add your document with Add->Existing Item... context menu of your project.
2. Right-click on your document item in your Solution Explorer
3. Select Properties from the context menu
4. Change Build Action from Compile to Embedded Resource
5. ...
6. PROFIT!!!