# c# - How to add string to resources?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, forms, resources

how to add the string to the resources. So when I restart the program that string should be in the resources.
After when I add it how can I get it? For example:

```
textBox1.Text = // string that I've added;
```

Thanks...

Comment: Any reason why you prefer to have it as "resource" rather than just a plain text file on disk?

Comment: @Gray I don't want any problems with that string. For example when I save it as text file, it can deleted but I don't want that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and use resources in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90697/how-to-create-and-use-resources-in-net)

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599662/how-do-you-write-to-a-resource-file

Comment: why you don't use `database` ?

Comment: @zey I don't think it would be good to create database for 1 string

Comment: You can have a text file or xml file and go to file properties in visual studio and set the Buil Action property to "Content" or Embded Resource. so file will eb embded into target assembly, Users cant delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use settings they I've used them for a while and they work great. If you want to change the setting you can do this:

```
Settings.Default.YourSetting = //Something
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 4):

Resources are not the right solution for your problem, they are designed to provide various (language) versions of **constant** strings. Generating them during execution of the program is [possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84wt3w1.aspx) but not quite easy. Even if you succeed to generate them, saving the file would be also hard - they are stored in the .exe or .dll file, which is probably locked as it is just executing.

Use [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).